# Ubuntu freezes after Android MTP connected

Tags: android, mtp

I have a new issue with my Ubuntu: when I connect my Android phone as an MTP (Galaxy S5) to my laptop, Ubuntu says that it cannot not mount Android MTP then it freezes and nothing works even <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>.

While frozen my CPU fan speed will increases. I think there is a process that causes this problem. I don't want install Ubuntu again.

I'm new to Ubuntu and I tried everything that I know: like checking CPU and RAM usage with `htop`.

This is the last package that I installed for making Android ROMs:

```
sudo apt-get install gawk
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install lzop bison gperf build-essential zlib1g-dev zlib1g-dev:i386 g++-multilib libxml2-utils bzip2 libbz2-dev libbz2-1.0 libghc-bzlib-dev libsepol1-dev dpkg-dev make
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, solution was:

Android MM:
Settings->Advanced settings/options -> Debug options ->Verify applications - USB (disable)

The system will freeze/crash if this option is enabled.